# Error Creating Logfile During Silent Installation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm experiencing an error creating a logfile during an application installation script.  This is the first time I've used PowerShell for this purpose.  The reason for using it is that I need to dynamically build the option string during the installation, based on other software installed on the server.

The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to generate the error is as follows:

```
$cmd = '"Installer.exe" /s /v"INSTALLDIR=D:\ OPTION_1=VALUE_1 OPTION_2=VALUE_2 OPTION_3=VALUE_3 REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*v \"C:\Temp\Install_Log.log\" /qb"'
Invoke-Expression "cmd /c ${cmd}"
```

The error I receive is:

> Error opening installation log file.  Verify that the specified log
>   file location exists and is writable.

Note that `/qb` is being used for debugging purposes only. It will be changed to `/qn` prior to deployment; the script also fails when `/qn` is used.

However, when I open a Command Prompt in the correct folder and paste the contents of `$cmd` into it, the application installs as expected.  It also works as expected if I remove `/L*v \"C:\Temp\Install_Log.log\"` from `$cmd`.  The log path does exist.  I have also attempted to create the log file **prior** to executing the installer, but this also failed.

I'm developing and testing this in PowerShell v2.0, if that matters, since some of the servers this will be deployed to have 2.0 installed.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're launching `cmd /c` to execute the installation, and not just executing it directly from PowerShell?

Comment: ...cuz that's the way I originally learned to do it when writing a PowerShell script? :-D

Comment: Read this article first: [Windows IT Pro: Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm surprised you didn't say anything about the use of DOS Prompt

Comment: @Matt - good one - I would have, if it was in the question (did I miss it)? <grin>

Comment: try the Powershell escape char backquote instead of the backslash before the double quotes, like: `/L*v <backquote>"C:\Temp\Install_Log.log<backquote>"`